# Android PDF Writer(APW) Enconding

Tags: android, pdf, encoding

I am using Android PDF Write(APW) to create a PDF, but it doesn't work with some special characters(portuguese).

```
mypdf.addText(170, 50, 40,"Coração");
```

The standard enconding is:

```
mypdf.setFont(StandardFonts.SUBTYPE, StandardFonts.COURIER, StandardFonts.WIN_ANSI_ENCODING);
outputToFile("helloworld.pdf",pdfcontent,"ISO-8859-1");
```

I'v tried

```
outputToFile("helloworld.pdf",pdfcontent,"UTF-8");
outputToFile("helloworld.pdf",pdfcontent,"UTF-16");
outputToFile("helloworld.pdf",pdfcontent,"Cp1252");
```

and didn't succeed.
Any ideas what should I do?

EDIT

The method outputToFile is defined as:

```
    private void outputToFile(String fileName, String pdfContent, String encoding) {
    File newFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + fileName);
    try {
        newFile.createNewFile();
        try {
            FileOutputStream pdfFile = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
            pdfFile.write(pdfContent.getBytes(encoding));
            pdfFile.close();
        } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            //
        }
    } catch(IOException e) {
        //
    }
}
```

The method addText is defined as:

```
    public void addText(int leftPosition, int topPositionFromBottom, int fontSize, String text, String transformation) {
    addContent(
        "BT\n" +
        transformation + " " + Integer.toString(leftPosition) + " " + Integer.toString(topPositionFromBottom) + " Tm\n" +
        "/F" + Integer.toString(mPageFonts.size()) + " " + Integer.toString(fontSize) + " Tf\n" +
        "(" + text + ") Tj\n" +
        "ET\n"
    );
}
```

Besides, I change the font color to white adding the following rawcontent:

```
mypdf.addRawContent("1 1 1 rg\n");
```

Then I come back to the black font color:

```
    mypdf.addRawContent("0 0 0 rg\n");
```

Comment: `outputToFile` does what? That been asked a quick view at the sources of APW seems to indicate that it is not very flexible concerning fonts and encodings.

Comment: Ah, from PDFWriterDemo I assume. First of all: because the string contains offset references, you **must not** use a multi-byte or variable-byte-number encoding. Actually it is quite some nonsense that APW returns a string here instead of a byte array. Pdf documents are not text. That being said, you should show the code in which you actually add your special characters including the code you use to create and select font objects.

Comment: Ok, but how do you set the font to use before your `mypdf.addText(170, 50, 40,"Coração")` line? The reason for my asking this is that depending on which font you select how, the encoding required for your string may differ and maybe your characters are not selectable at all! E.g. ã (atilde) in the built-in encodings may have the octal value 213, 343, or 343 (MacRomanEncoding, WinAnsiEncoding, PDFDocEncoding, cf. Annex D of the PDF [specification](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf)), and the font you use must contain the character to start with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I took all the information provided, wrote the following simple unit test method and ran it.

```
public void test19192108()
{
    PDFWriter mPDFWriter = new PDFWriter(PaperSize.FOLIO_WIDTH, PaperSize.FOLIO_HEIGHT);
    mPDFWriter.setFont(StandardFonts.SUBTYPE, StandardFonts.COURIER, StandardFonts.WIN_ANSI_ENCODING);
    mPDFWriter.addText(170, 50, 40,"Coração");

    String pdfcontent = mPDFWriter.asString();
    outputToFile("helloworld19192108.pdf",pdfcontent,"ISO-8859-1");
}
```

(`outputToFile`being the helper method from the APW `PDFWriterDemo` class)

The result looks like this:

[image: Screenshot of helloworld19192108.pdf in Adobe Reader]

This seems pretty much to fulfill the expectations.

Thus, in whichever way *it doesn't work with some special characters(portuguese)* for the OP, some vital information is missing for reproducing the issue.

PS: Depending on the setup of the development environment, there might be an issue with non-ASCII characters in the source code. Thus, it might be a good idea to replace

```
    mPDFWriter.addText(170, 50, 40,"Coração");
```

with

```
    mPDFWriter.addText(170, 50, 40,"Cora\u00e7\u00e3o");
```

PPS: Adobe Reader after viewing a file generated like this wants to repair it. The reason is that the cross reference table is broken. The code generating entries for it is this:

```
public void addObjectXRefInfo(int ByteOffset, int Generation, boolean InUse) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(String.format("%010d", ByteOffset));
    sb.append(" ");
    sb.append(String.format("%05d", Generation));
    if (InUse) {
        sb.append(" n ");
    } else {
        sb.append(" f ");
    }
    sb.append("\r\n");
    mList.add(sb.toString());
}
```

> *(from [CrossReferenceTable.java](http://sourceforge.net/p/apwlibrary/code/11/tree/CrossReferenceTable.java))*

Counting the characters in this entry we get 10 + 1 + 5 + 3 + 2 = 21.

According to the specification, though:

> Each entry shall be exactly 20 bytes long, including the end-of-line marker
>
> *(from section 7.5.4* Cross-Reference Table *of [ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf))*

When using (the current version of) the Android PDF Writer, you should fix this code, too.

Comment: What I didn't mentioned is that I change the color, adding rawcontent to the File, like this: mypdf.addRawContent("1 1 1 rg\n"); Is that right?

Comment: What you have not mentioned yet, also includes what **exactly does not work for you**. Up to now i only see that things do work as long as one does not count the cross reference issue.

Comment: I don't know whether you can change the color because you do not tell what exactly **does not work for you**.

Comment: You, sir, are a saint! I was so caught up with the meta-info Adobe adds that I haven't even noticed the error with the cross-reference table! Thank you very much for this outstanding answer! I was literally aging from so much stress!