# getting error when generating many items with PDFWriter

Tags: android, pdf

I have been developing application which can generate PDF from scanning barcode item process, but if I want to generate 10-13 items, the programm can work, but if I generate more than 20 items, then I get crashed with my programm

Here the logcat error :

```
11-07 13:40:06.463: E/AndroidRuntime(9538): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
11-07 13:40:06.463: E/AndroidRuntime(9538): Process: com.example.testpdf, PID: 9538
11-07 13:40:06.463: E/AndroidRuntime(9538): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
11-07 13:40:06.463: E/AndroidRuntime(9538):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
11-07 13:40:06.463: E/AndroidRuntime(9538):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
11-07 13:40:06.463: E/AndroidRuntime(9538):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
11-07 13:40:06.463: E/AndroidRuntime(9538):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
11-07 13:40:06.463: E/AndroidRuntime(9538):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
11-07 13:40:06.463: E/AndroidRuntime(9538):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
11-07 13:40:06.463: E/AndroidRuntime(9538):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
11-07 13:40:06.463: E/AndroidRuntime(9538):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
11-07 13:40:06.463: E/AndroidRuntime(9538): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
11-07 13:40:06.463: E/AndroidRuntime(9538):     at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:422)
11-07 13:40:06.463: E/AndroidRuntime(9538):     at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.toString(AbstractStringBuilder.java:642)
11-07 13:40:06.463: E/AndroidRuntime(9538):     at java.lang.StringBuilder.toString(StringBuilder.java:663)
11-07 13:40:06.463: E/AndroidRuntime(9538):     at com.example.pdfwriter.PDFDocument.toPDFString(PDFDocument.java:69)
11-07 13:40:06.463: E/AndroidRuntime(9538):     at com.example.pdfwriter.PDFWriter.asString(PDFWriter.java:113)
11-07 13:40:06.463: E/AndroidRuntime(9538):     at com.example.testpdf.ViewOfferOrder$Ganeratetask.generateHelloWorldPDF(ViewOfferOrder.java:1048)
11-07 13:40:06.463: E/AndroidRuntime(9538):     at com.example.testpdf.ViewOfferOrder$Ganeratetask.doInBackground(ViewOfferOrder.java:652)
11-07 13:40:06.463: E/AndroidRuntime(9538):     at com.example.testpdf.ViewOfferOrder$Ganeratetask.doInBackground(ViewOfferOrder.java:1)
11-07 13:40:06.463: E/AndroidRuntime(9538):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
11-07 13:40:06.463: E/AndroidRuntime(9538):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
11-07 13:40:06.463: E/AndroidRuntime(9538):     ... 4 more
```

and then the error refer to (pdfwritter class) :

```
public String asString() {
        mPages.render();
        return mDocument.toPDFString();
    }
```

Can somebody help me to solve this problem ?

Comment: Your stacktrace looks very much like you use the APW Android PDF Writer library refactored to the `com.example` package. Please be aware that APW is very resource hungry: It creates the whole PDF in memory and actually does so in a very prodigal way using `chars` where it could (and should!) use `bytes`. This would explain out-of-memory situations. Furthermore, when using the APW code, check whether the xref table bug (cf. the PPS in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19251644/1729265)) has been fixed.

Comment: do you have solution brother ? because I still cannot find good library for PDF writer which can render image also.

Comment: I'm neither deep into PDF rendering nor into Android programming. Thus, no, I have no immediate solution. I merely once stumbled over APW and was somewhat taken aback.