# Android PDF Writer(APW) Polish characters enconding

Tags: android, pdf

In Android PDF Write(APW) for creating PDF files (link to the library: http://sourceforge.net/projects/apwlibrary/) I am having a problem with Polish characters. I am looking for a solution or an adjustment in the library fix this.

Polish set of characters (Please note Polish is in Latin 2):

```
mypdf.addText(10,10,12,"ŚĆĄĘŃŻŹÓŁ śćąęńżźół");
```

In XObjectImage class I changed from:

```
public static String ENCODING = "ISO-8859-1";
```

to:

```
public static String ENCODING = "ISO-8859-2";
```

In StandardFonts I added:

```
public static final String ISO8859_2 = "ISO8859-2";
```

I tried to put this combination in:

```
mypdf.setFont(StandardFonts.SUBTYPE,StandardFonts.COURIER,StandardFonts.ISO8859_2);
outputToFile("my.pdf",pdfcontent,"ISO-8859-2");
```

It does not work yet. Please help me adding additional adjustments in the library in order to run Polish characters correctly.

Comment: Have you made sure your *Polish characters* are represented in `WIN_ANSI_ENCODING`? Concerning APW you should furthermore consider the bug mentioned [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19251644/1729265).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Android PDF Write(APW) is only made for using the standard 14 fonts in a predefined encoding (**MacRomanEncoding**, **MacExpertEncoding**, or **WinAnsiEncoding**), see below.

If you lookup the definition of these encodings (Annex D.2 *Latin Character Set and Encodings* and D.4 *Expert Set and MacExpertEncoding* in the [PDF specification](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf)), you will see that your characters `"ŚĆĄĘŃŻŹÓŁ śćąęńżźół"` are not (at least not all, I merely sampled) present in these encodings.

Furthermore PDF viewers only are required to provide the standard 14 fonts in the given encodings (cf. section 9.6.2.2 *Standard Type 1 Fonts (Standard 14 Fonts)* in the [PDF specification](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf)). Thus, you cannot expect PDF viewers reliably to be able to display your characters with those fonts.

***Thus, if you need those characters, you have to either extend APW to allow for different fonts and encosings or switch to a different PDF creation library.***

### Only standard 14 fonts

I claimed above:

> The Android PDF Write(APW) is only made for using the standard 14 fonts

This is because uses the following code for generating font dictionaries in the class `Page`

```
public void setFont(String subType, String baseFont) {
    IndirectObject lFont = mDocument.newIndirectObject();
    mDocument.includeIndirectObject(lFont);
    lFont.setDictionaryContent("  /Type /Font\n  /Subtype /" + subType + "\n  /BaseFont /" + baseFont + "\n");
    mPageFonts.add(lFont);
}

public void setFont(String subType, String baseFont, String encoding) {
    IndirectObject lFont = mDocument.newIndirectObject();
    mDocument.includeIndirectObject(lFont);
    lFont.setDictionaryContent("  /Type /Font\n  /Subtype /" + subType + "\n  /BaseFont /" + baseFont + "\n  /Encoding /" + encoding + "\n");
    mPageFonts.add(lFont);
}
```

As you see only entries **Type**, **Subtype**, **BaseFont**, and optionally **Encoding** are created. If you lookup the font related subsections of section 9 *Text* in the [PDF specification](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf), you will see that for fonts other than the standard 14 fonts more entries are required.

Thus, APW only properly supports standard 14 fonts.

### Only predefined encoding (**MacRomanEncoding**, **MacExpertEncoding**, or **WinAnsiEncoding**)

I claimed above:

> The Android PDF Write(APW) is only made for using ... a predefined encoding (**MacRomanEncoding**, **MacExpertEncoding**, or **WinAnsiEncoding**)

As you see in the code quoted above, if an encoding is selected at all, this is done using `"\n  /Encoding /" + encoding + "\n"`, and the leading `'/'` means that the `encoding` is a PDF name, not a PDF dictionary.

According to the specification

> **Encoding** name or
>   dictionary
>   *(Optional)* A specification of the font’s character encoding if different
>   from its built-in encoding. The value of Encoding shall be either the
>   name of a predefined encoding (**MacRomanEncoding**,
>   **MacExpertEncoding**, or **WinAnsiEncoding**, as described in Annex
>   D) or an encoding dictionary that shall specify differences from the
>   font’s built-in encoding or from a specified predefined encoding (see
>   9.6.6, "Character Encoding").
>
> *(Table 111 – Entries in a Type 1 font dictionary - [PDF specification](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) )*

this only allows for **MacRomanEncoding**,
**MacExpertEncoding**, or **WinAnsiEncoding**. (As PDF viewers bring along their own, individual font programs to use for standard 14 fonts, you cannot rely on the *built-in encoding* to help you in any reliable way.)