# pdfWriter out of memory(android)

Tags: android, pdf

Sorry for my english. I use android [pdf writer library](http://sourceforge.net/p/apwlibrary/code/HEAD/tree/)( please do not offer me iText - because library something like this have not good license for me). Its libruary work, but when i want create for example 4 pages in each page have 1 image its say me **out of memory**. I dont know why i have this error, i spend many time for fix this bug but this did not work out.

My code:

```
     @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            String pdfcontent = generateHelloWorldPDF();
            outputToScreen(R.id.text, pdfcontent);
            outputToFile("helloworld.pdf", pdfcontent, "ISO-8859-1");
        }


//generation pdf
      private String generateHelloWorldPDF(){
            String s = null;
            try{
                //this list have image(size, name)
                ArrayList<FileObject> listFile = ....
                AssetManager mngr = getAssets();
                PDFWriter mPDFWriter = new PDFWriter(500, 600);


                for(int i = 0; i < listFile.size(); i++) {

                    if(i != 0) mPDFWriter.newPage();
                    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(String.valueOf(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/test/" + listFile.get(i).getName())));
                    mPDFWriter.addImage(0, 0, image, Transformation.DEGREES_0_ROTATION);

                    s = mPDFWriter.asString();
                }

                s = mPDFWriter.asString();
            }catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("error", e.toString());
            }

            return s;
        }

//create file
private void outputToFile(String fileName, String pdfContent, String encoding) {
        File newFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + fileName);
        try {
            newFile.createNewFile();
            try {
                FileOutputStream pdfFile = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
                pdfFile.write(pdfContent.getBytes(encoding));
                pdfFile.close();
            } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
                //
            }
        } catch(IOException e) {
            //
        }
    }
```

And i have

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
                                                     at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:122)
                                                     at com.example.alexy.converttopdf.XObjectImage.encodeImageData(XObjectImage.java:114)
                                                     at com.example.alexy.converttopdf.XObjectImage.processImage(XObjectImage.java:132)
                                                     at com.example.alexy.converttopdf.XObjectImage.<init>(XObjectImage.java:43)
                                                     at com.example.alexy.converttopdf.PDFWriter.addImage(PDFWriter.java:96)
                                                     at com.example.alexy.converttopdf.MainActivity.generateHelloWorldPDF(MainActivity.java:90)
                                                     at com.example.alexy.converttopdf.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:59)
                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**MainActivity59** it `String pdfcontent = generateHelloWorldPDF();`

**MaintActivity90** it `mPDFWriter.addImage(0, 0, image, Transformation.DEGREES_0_ROTATION);`

for example if i do lke this  `for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)` its work. If i do like this  `for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)` -> **out of memory**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Android PDF Writer (APW)](http://sourceforge.net/projects/apwlibrary/) library simply requires much memory because it

- keeps the whole PDF (as multiple partial objects) in memory during creation,
- stores it in memory in `Strings` or `StringBuilder' which effectively doubles memory usage and enforces ASCII85 encoding of binaries bloating them even more,
- while adding images temporarily uses a `byte[]` containing the completely uncompressed bitmap,
- while finalizing the PDF adding all partial PDF objects to another `StringBuilder` effectively doubling the required memory at this moment once again,
- ...

When using this library, therefore, always keep this resource hunger in mind and abstain from adding multiple large entities (e.g. images).

BTW, APW has a bug when creating the internal PDF cross references, cf. the post-postscript in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19251644/1729265).